# CGGradientCreateWithColors / CGContextDrawLinearGradient - formula to calculate intermediate colour combinations?

Tags: swift, objective-c, core-graphics, quartz-2d

Does anyone know the formula used by CGGradientCreateWithColors to calculate the intermediate colours at each point along the gradient? I want to reproduce the colour for a given point - e.g. with CGGradientCreateWithColors using only 2 colours set to locations = 0 and 1, what would be the colour on the gradient at point 0.2 or any other defined point between 0 and 1?
I use CGContextDrawLinearGradient to draw the background of one UIView with the full gradient, but I also want to colour a second UIView with the colour for a specific distance along the gradient, which would vary according to a value mapped to the 0..1 scale.

Any suggestions how to get this blend of the two colours to match the colour at a fixed point along the CGGradient wouild be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just read the color at a given point in the drawing of the gradient? In other words, instead of trying to guess how this is calculated behind the scenes, just _look_ at it (programmatically of course).

Comment: Thanks Matt I did think about that but this would involve setting up a context, drawing the gradient, then sampling a pixel at the correct distance which is a bit time consuming. I hoped that there would be a simple formula for how to get the calculated RGB values for the points directly.

Comment: Well, you can assume that the gradient is linear, so you can just use the standard interpolated value between the two end points, without needing to supply a curve. But you also have to get the color space right. What I would do is develop the formula by guesswork and test it against the reality by reading the pixel, and once you've got it right, throw away the test code.

Comment: Quickly testing, what about doing `UIColor(red: red1 * percent + red2 * (1 - percent), green: green1 * percent + green2 * (1 - percent), blue: blue1 * percent + blue2 * (1 - percent), alpha: alpha1 * percent + alpha2 * (1 - percent))` where `red1` & `red2` are the components of the colors, and percent the position ?

Comment: Thanks Larme, this gives exactly the effect that I need - whether or not it is the actual formula behind CGGradientCreateWithColors.

Answer (score 1):

Larme's formula does the trick for me, where the proportion of the second colour (colour at location 1.0 in CGGradientCreateWithColors) that you want expressed (i.e. the "distance" between colour at 0.0 and colour at 1.0) is P in the formula below. The proportion of colour 0 expressed then becomes (1 -  P). P is a value between 0..1, so (to state the obvious) 75% of colour 1 gives P = 0.75, and this means colour 0 has 25% expression (1 - 0.75).

```
CGFloat P = 0.75; // any value between 0.0 .. 1.0
CGFloat b = 1 - P;
UIColor* col0 = [UIColor yellowColour]; // or whatever ...
UIColor* col1 = [UIColor redColor]; // or whatever ...
CGFloat R0,R1,G0,G1,B0,B1,A0,A1;
[col0 getRed:&R0 green:&G0 blue:&B0 alpha:&A0];
[col1 getRed:&R1 green:&G1 blue:&B1 alpha:&A1];
UIColor* blendedColour = [UIColor 
    colorWithRed: R1 * P + R0 * b 
    green:        G1 * P + G0 * b 
    blue:         B1 * P + B0 * b
    alpha:        A1 * P + A0 * b];
// P = 0.75 gives red-orange colour. P = 0.5 gives orange. etc.
```